# Custom Application permissions and authorizations when Authenticating to Azure

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

In a hypothetical scenario where I am using Microsoft Identity Platform for authentication, how would I also leverage it to control user permissions. Specifically, user permissions within the custom app. These permissions would not be related to other Azure resources or apps. For example, a web app that allows various different operators of a production plant to enable and disable different systems in the plant such as water coolers, air compressors, and conveyor belts. If I have a web app that allows a user to control these devices on a plant floor, how can I use MSAL to control the permissions to these different areas in the app? I only want user A to control coolers and compressors, and I only want user B to control the belts. I already know how to authenticate the users to the application using MSAL. I would prefer to control the permissions using something similar to AzureAD groups unless there is something better suited to this use case.

Answer (score 2):

**Scenario 1:**

You have a Web App containing all the business logic. For this scenario you create one app registration for your Web App in Azure AD and define app roles for the various operators. You can name these app roles anything you want, for example: Coolers.Control and Belts.Control.

[**Example App Registration for Web App with App Roles (Image)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxfbE.png)

These roles can be assigned to individual users or groups in Azure AD at the Enterprise Application page. If you click on the "How do I assign App roles" on the app roles page, you will find the link that will redirect you to the Enterprise Application page.

If the user navigates to your Web App and signs in using the authorization code flow, the OAuth 2.0 authorization endpoint will return an Identity Token including a roles claim. You can use these roles in your web application to determine what areas the user is allowed to access.

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-overview?tabs=aspnetcore

**Scenario 2:**

But there is another option that you might want to consider. You could also create a Web App for UI logic only and place the business logic in a separate Web API. With this architecture you are able to allow multiple (future) client applications to use the functionality of the API, for example: native mobile apps or background apps.

For your scenario you would create two app registrations: one for your Web App and one for your Web API. You define the app roles in the app registration for the Web API and define a scope, for example: access_as_user, to allow delegated access. This scope needs to be assigned to the app registration for your Web App.

[**Example App Registration for Web API with Scope (Image)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7MjP.png)

In the Web App you use the access_as_user scope (including app id prefix) in the call to the authorization endpoint. If the user signs in and grants this scope to the Web App so it can call the Web API on behalf of the signed-in user, the authorization endpoint returns an Access Token. If the app roles are defined in the app registration of the Web API and assigned to the user, the Access Token will contain a roles claim. This token is meant for the Web API to authorize the user. When the Web App calls the Web API, it also sends this Access Token in the Authorization Header of the HTTP request. The Web API determines what the user is allowed to do based on the roles in the Access Token.

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview

**Additional information:**

Because I had a similar question, I wrote an article about understanding scopes and app roles in Azure AD. The article explains how to use both scopes and app roles in a delegated access scenario, and how to use app roles in an app-only access scenario. I think this answers your question about how to control the permissions using something similar to Azure AD groups.

URL: https://cloudfirstapproach.com/understanding-oauth-scopes-and-roles-in-azure-ad/